# Can Bootstrap 2 markup be made to work with Bootstrap 3 CSS/LESS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have a project with *lots* of old Bootstrap 2 markup (.row-fluid, span6 etc.).
I'd like to update the project to Bootstrap 3, but modifying the legacy html is not possible (for complicated reasons).

Is there a way to make old Bootstrap 2 markup (mostly scaffolding) work with Bootstrap 3?

Comment: No way, change all classes is the only solution.

Comment: There is, of course, a solution. I could write the LESS/CSS for .row-fluid, .span6 etc myself by hand.
I'm hoping there is a better/already build solution.

Comment: No since using the Bootstrap framework is based on using it's CSS classes in the HTML markup

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to update your HTML (depending on how many pages you have) you could try this: http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/

Just paste your bootstrap 2 code in and get bootstrap 3 out.

Comment: The legacy HTML cannot be modified.